# Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I am fetching a list of items as a radio buttons. User has to select any one item from the list and i need to pass that selected item to the service. It is working for the first item from the list but throwing System.IndexOutOfRangeException and System.Web.HttpUnhandledException exceptions for all the items except first one.
    Below is my code:

```
string selecteditem = this.Request.Form["Cardholder_edit"];
list[] legalList =
                this.ResultList.Content.legalList.Select(
                getAllUsers =>
                    new list
                    {
                        itemNumber = getAllUsers.list.itemNumber,
                        itemNumber1 = getAllUsers.list.itemNumber1,
                        itemCode = getAllUsers.list.itemCode,
                        itemstore = getAllUsers.list.itemstore,

                    }).ToArray();

            var Data = new Request
            {
                    enrolselected = legalList[Convert.ToInt32(selecteditem.Substring(selecteitem.Length - 1)) - 1],                 
            };
```

can someone help me on this? what is the alternative to pass information of only one selected radiobutton?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing same without **this**

and refer this similar question here, b/c it is the same reason why you are having access only to the first item.
Hope this will help, Cheers!

Comment: I could not see any link or code here. which code i refer?